# error: "Cannot create an existing file" when it does not actually exist

Tags: python, mkdir

I'm coding a sound recording and analysis program in python but I have a problem with the command (on first run it worked great but since IMPOSSIBLE):

```
os.mkdir(directory)
```

As output I get this:

```
An exception occurred: FileExistsError
[WinError 183] Could not create an already existing file: '\\output'
```

While in my code I check in the following way in case the folder is indeed already existing:

```
current_dir = os.getcwd()

# Define a "output" directory :
directory = "\\"+"output"

path = current_dir + directory

isExist = os.path.exists(path)      # Valeure booléenne


if not isExist:
    # Create the directory
    # 'result' in
    # current directory
    os.mkdir(directory)
```

I checked with the debugger and **the "isExist" variable has the value "False"** but when running the program tells me that the folder already exists ??? Weird...
[image]

And of course the "output" folder does not appear in the file explorer! Completely illogical...
[image]

Note that this code is in a GitHub repository so maybe the error comes from there but the repository does not contain an "output" folder either!

Thanks in advance to anyone who tries to help me.

Comment: You check `path` but you create `directory`.

Comment: You check if `path` exists and try to create `directory` it it doesn't. `directory` starts with a backslash indicating it's meant to go at the root of the current drive (i.e. something like `C:\output`). So I'm pretty sure you've created that one in a previous run. In the future make sure that what you check is actually what you're trying to manipulate and not just something similar.

Comment: Thank You Guys and yes that is the mistake I made, both folders are present at the root D:\\. I realized it right after asking the question but so I changed "os.mkdir(directory)" to "os.mkdir(path)"

Answer (score 0):

Ok well I found the solution, in reality you have to replace "directory" by "path" in the command:

```
os.mkdir(path)
```

Because otherwise it will only work the first run and even if you manually delete the folder.

So here is the code if it can help someone else!

```
import os

current_dir = os.getcwd()

# Define a "output" directory :

directory = "\\"+"output"

path = current_dir + directory

isExist = os.path.exists(path)      # Valeure booléenne


if not isExist:
    # Create the directory
    # 'output' in
    # current directory
    os.mkdir(path)
```

Comment: I would import `pathlib` from Pythons standard library and use it with `path = pathlib.Path.cwd() / 'output'` followed by `path.mkdir(exist_ok=True)`. That's all.

Comment: @Matthias Yes it's a much simpler method, I'll do that! Thanks